# Glitchy, pixilated text and icons after resuming from suspend

Tags: nvidia, graphics, suspend, gnome-shell, 21.04

After resuming from suspend, the login screen has glitchy, pixilated text and icons.

Then, after logging in, the dock and the top bar also have these same glitches.

Newly opened windows do not have this problem.

I am using Ubuntu 21.04, nvidia-utils-460, and XOrg.

Does anyone know to fix this?

I can make this go away by restarting gnome shell using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd>, but is there a permanent solution?

Here is what it looks like (I've cropped the screen shot into three parts to highlight relevant areas of the deskotp).

[image]

Comment: It's been happening for many years, many cards, many drivers version...

Comment: I've used many different versions of Ubuntu on this laptop over the years. This is the first time I am seeing it (with Ubuntu 21.04).